# Why is one day's null data two days wide?

Tags: highcharts

When plotting time-series data, assume I have counts per day of something. Demo data:

```
Jan 1: 10
Jan 2: 20
Jan 3: 30
Jan 4: <no data>
Jan 5: 50
Jan 6: 60
etc.
```

Note that data is missing for *one* day, Jan 4.

When show this in highcharts ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmorch/6c1q72od/)), it looks like this:

[image: jsfiddle screenshot]

Note how the "gap" for the missing day is two days wide. Why? How do I avoid this?

What I'm hoping for is to show data for Jan 3 as a vertical line like this:

[image: manually fixed jsfiddle screenshot]

I can't just cheat and add 6 hours to the timestamp and use `step: "left"` because such cheating will be revealed when the user zooms in and more precise time stamps start showing up.

Comment: Short answer: it's not. As a demo, remove the line, enable markers, and you should see why that makes sense. You're thinking of the line segment as if it's the top of a column, and expecting one to extend into the area between data, which it can't without a point to connect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My boss had a bright idea: In addition to having a data point at the beginning of an interval, why not just create some fake data points at the end of the intervals? So that data instead becomes:

```
Jan 1 00:00:00: 10
Jan 1 23:59:59: 10
Jan 2 00:00:00: 20
Jan 2 23:59:59: 20
Jan 3 00:00:00: 30
Jan 3 23:59:59: 30
Jan 4 00:00:00: <no data>
Jan 4 23:59:59: <no data>
Jan 5 00:00:00: 50
Jan 5 23:59:59: 50
Jan 6 00:00:00: 60
Jan 6 23:59:59: 60
etc.
```

It works beautifully! ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmorch/bp3p9vs9/)):

[image: solution]

(This of course has the drawback of presenting Highcharts with twice the amount of data potentially causing performance problems)

Answer (score 2):

It is not 2 days wide. You have your data on 3.Jan and 5.Jan. The entire width is that one date. Your points are at midnight for each day. You have no data that goes for an entire day (midnight to midnight). So you have 24 hours with no data between 3.Jan and 5.Jan. To solve you would need to add more time-based data or maybe use a category xAxis

Comment: This makes me so sad... Maybe that is how Highcharts wants to present it. But it does not reflect actual reality. My data does  *NOT* represent a single measurement performed at midnight. I did not count 50 of something exactly at midnight. The value of 50 is for the entire 24 hour period of midnight-to-midnight.

And if I use a category xAxis, the user cannot zoom in. On the server I have data in finer granularity, but I don't think the user will be able to get at it if I use a category xAxis. I'll clarify the question.

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch, why are you not able to zoom if you use a category xAxis? Sample from API docs on zooming where I just changed chart type to 'column' = http://jsfiddle.net/6a1Lo2L4/

Answer (score 0):

@wergeld's answer led me to realize I had asked the wrong question. So I accepted @wergeld's answer, but wanted to provide some more details here:

The problem isn't only with the width of the `null` data, but the underlying assumption that

```
xAxis: { type: 'datetime' }
```

means that data represents a *single point in time*. I have time-series data, where each data point represents a time *interval* (see below).

I don't think HighCharts allows me to chart that as I want.

I guess I have to use a category xAxis. ( The interval lengths could vary between "columns" - I'll ignore that for now. )

Server-side, we have the intervals in much finer granularity, so zooming-in does actually make sense for us. I've just discovered to my surprise that zooming does work also for category xAxis charts ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmorch/0wq4o2q7/)):

[image: zoomable column highchart]

So that is what I'll do:

- Use a category xAxis
- Pretend all columns are equally wide
- Make them zoomable by listening to the `setExtremes` xAxis event (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmorch/0wq4o2q7/))

#### Footnote about derivatives with respect to time

I'd argue that every time measured data represents a derivative with respect to time (and has units like  e.g. `bits/s` or `$/month`), then a measurement performed at a t<sub>n</sub> really represents the time interval

[ t<sub>n-1</sub> ; t<sub>n</sub> ]

and not a single-point-in-time such as t<sub>n</sub> because when it is measured, the "derivative" it is calculated/approximated as: Δbits / Δt, but Δt is not close to 0 in actual fact.

E.g. sales pr. month is for the month of April, not for either April 1st or May 1st at 12am.

So Highchart's (and flot's?) approach of pretending that all time-series data represents a single point in time creates graphs that are misleading and hard to interpret correctly.

Comment: I do not think Highcharts is "pretending" that all time-series data represents a single point in time - your data is telling it is a single point in time. Think timestamps on log file entries or scheduled event times. If what you want is some integral/derivative chart you have to accept that in the digital world where you want to display the data is non-continuous - it is discreet. You need to tell Highcharts (or any other chart library) that you want the y-value to be the same across your set interval in order to make that step line.

Comment: @wergeld: Thank you so much for trying to help me understand. What does : "If what you want is some integral/derivative chart you have to accept that in the digital world where you want to display the data is non-continuous - it is discreet" mean (honestly - I didn't understand the sentence)? Sure, perhaps the library I want to use doesn't support what I need, but why accept that "it isn't possible"? You write: "You need to tell Highcharts (or any other chart library) that you want the y-value to be the same across your set interval in order to make that step line" Exactly! How do I do that?

Comment: What I mean by "discreet" is that you are telling the chart library that at this exact time the value of y was 100 for example. By "step" I mean maybe change your chart type to `line` and use the `step` parameter. Then also change to use datetime xAxis and enable zoom like: http://jsfiddle.net/2p9zkb31/. This lists the 3 types of steps. Maybe 'center' would be what you need.

Comment: `line` and `step` is exactly what I used in my original question and exactly as far as I got. Which brings me back to: 1) How do I avoid one day's missing data causing a gap in the chart 2 days wide? 2) If I want to use `step: "center"`, then I have to fiddle with the timestamp to manually make it in the middle of the interval, which has a smell. I really do appreciate you spending your time so far on this, @wergeld.

Comment: If all your data is just for one day intervals (although I am not sure because the last bit of data in your example looks like it is hourly) then you can use categories for your xAxis. This will have the effect of letting you dictate how a point is displayed and the "gap" between data points.

Comment: Thanks, wergeld. Using categories for xAxis is exactly the solution I used in this answer. With the drawback that then I have to actually implement the time-based xAxis labels myself. And (I guess) I'll run into problems when the time intervals (columns) don't have the same width. As a minimum, it makes the whole thing more complicated.